# Minecraft launcher not recognizing I've paid for the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

When I load my launcher, all goes well except logging in. Once I log in to my old account it doesn't let me play the full game. Once I sign in it says "Welcome Guest" and forces me to play on a guest account. I spent the full $25 for it and don't plan on spending it again. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Are you logging in to the correct account?

Comment: Yes I am, I even changed the password on it to make sure.

Comment: Some old launcher only support demo, I recommend you to change your Minecraft launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You say old account so I'm going to assume you haven't hooked it up to a mojang account yet. If not I suggest you go to the mojang website and register your game with a mojang account.

Comment: The last time I played on it was 1.8.2. I also migrated my account in February.

Comment: @Bradon have you entered your email correctly?

Comment: I have, all of the information is correct. It just won't let me play anything other than Guest

Comment: @Bradon have you tried redownloading minecraft?

Comment: Just did. Ever since I got the game it has never done this but once I reset my desktop and redownloaded it, its said Guest.

Comment: @Bradon It might have something to do with internet connection. Any screenshots would probably help. If not, I'm at a loss and you might have to contact mojang support or something like that.

Comment: Now that I've tried logging in, it's said "Wrong Password".

Comment: @Bradon You changed it right? Have you confirmed it in your email address? Are you inputting the new password? Are you using the correct email? Make sure all of those things are correct.

Comment: I'm gonna reset the password one more time. If this doesn't work I'm going to send a complaint letter to Mojang.

Comment: @Bradon ok tell me how it goes

Comment: Now that I changed the password. It's telling me that either my Username or Password is incorrect even though they are both correct, I triple checked.

Comment: @Bradon You're using your email right? For the username?

Comment: Yes I am, I've migrated and everything.

Comment: @Bradon Well, I have exhausted my ideas for how to fix it. I think you should contact mojang.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the cooperation though.

Comment: @Bradon No Problem, sorry I couldn't do more.